# jQuery Datepicker style

Tags: jquery, css, datepicker

on my page http://pagina.chalupakoseckerovne.sk/ in last section I used jQuery Datepicker inline. But I have a problem with style, even when change the css for that div. Its still inherited.

```
#rezervovane
{
    font: 16px/24px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif !important;
    text-transform:none !important;
    vertical-align:auto !important;
    float:none !important;
}
```

I also used Datepicker in form on left, 6th and 7th input, but there is style ok.
Can you halp me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found most problem happens at `layout.css` at `line: 171`

Commenting out the following CSS is fixing the most of the problems

```
.contact-section span {
  float: right;
  font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Try to find a way to rewrite above CSS which will not affect DatePicker css